# How to check if a Carbon date object is at the start of day?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) to manipulate dates I retrieved from my MySQL database. I have dates like the following:

- `2017-07-19 00:00:00`
- `2017-06-26 15:27:57`

As you can see, the first is the start of a day. When displaying dates like that, I would like to omit the time part. I know I can use a different format for each one. For example:

- `F d Y` for dates without time.
- `F d Y g:ia` for dates with time.

What I couldn't accomplish is a simple way to check if a date has a time part to apply one format or the other. Must I use individual getters to check the hour, minute and second?

Comment: It is start of the day and end of the previous day.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you just want to check if it's the start of the day, then it's fairly easy to check with Carbon's `startOfDay()` [modifier](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers) and a [comparison](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison):

```
$date = Carbon::now(); // or whatever you're using to set it
$start = $date->copy()->startOfDay();
if($date->eq($start)) {
    // do your formatting here
}
```

Comment: Hey, @aynber. This is an interesting approach. In terms of code styling, it's better than check each time property (hour, minute and second).

Comment: Carbon has some great functions for modifying and comparing dates and time. The links I provided are for the Carbon docs, and you can see all of the different functions.

Answer (score 6):

In the meanwhile its even easier. Use the `is....()` methods (see [carbon comparison](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)) like this:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
if($date->isStartOfDay()) {     // check if hour is 00:00:00
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: Probably this function didn't exist at the time I posted the question, 2 years ago. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the timestamp of the Carbon object minus the timestamp of "today" (which is `yyyy-mm-dd 0000:00:00`) and it will give you the number of seconds that passed from `00:00` to that date:

```
$secondsPassed = $carbonObject->timestamp - $carbonObject->copy()->startOfDay()->timestamp;
if ($secondsPassed > 8 * 60 * 60) {
    // time is passed 08:00 am
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Dekel. Thanks, but it seems that will work only for dates in the current day.

Comment: You are right, answer updated. Changed the `today` to the `startOfDay()` of the CarbonObject you have